# How to open multiple instances of Alacritty on macOS?

Tags: macos, user-interface, new-window, alacritty

macOS 11.4 , Alacritty 0.8.0 installed from homebrew 3.2.5 , although this should not matter because the question is mostly related to macOS UI.

What I want to do is something equivalent to `Terminal.app`'s `right click on icon > New Window` sort of thing; Alacritty does not support windows.

On Linux, I'm used to launching new instance of `alacritty` with `background` option in `dmenu`.

On a mac, what would a similar action look like ?

Comment: I must say I don't quite understand why this question was closed? Isn't Alacritty a tool primarily used by programmers, thus making it a valid question? Anyways, the answer saved my dumb butt, so thanks :)

Comment: I use Alacritty as my main IDE for development, so I don't see why this question was closed?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think pressing command + N does the trick